# JMeter: Parameter and its values are not getting captured by JMeter for Mobile App

Tags: parameters, jmeter

We have a scenario where we need to logina and navigate to home screen of android native app. After recording the scenario, in Request we dnt see Parameters and its value getting captured, not available even in header manager.It shows "generate_204/" Is it hidden? How do Iproceed further with the scripting?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be recording requests to Google domain.

Looking into [Network Portal Detection](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/network-portal-detection) article at least Chromium OS uses `http://clients3.google.com/generate_204` URL to check whether it is online or it's captive.

Looking into [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) command output

```
yngwie$ curl -v http://clients1.google.com/generate_204
*   Trying 172.217.16.46...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to clients1.google.com (172.217.16.46) port 80 (#0)
> GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1
> Host: clients1.google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 11 Jun 2018 04:56:37 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host clients1.google.com left intact
```

it is empty request which returns [HTTP 204 (No Content)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) response.

So you should **exclude** these calls from your recording (optional but recommended) and replay (strongly recommended) as this call doesn't have anything in common with your application.

If you are not able to see your application traffic - most probably your application uses [HTTPS protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) for communication with the backend, you will need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate on your mobile device in order to be able to decrypt and record HTTPS traffic. See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) User Manual entry for more information.

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test, in this case you won't have to worry about SSL certificates, moreover you will be able to export your tests in SmartJMX mode with automatic detection and correlation of any dynamic parameters. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for more details.